# Does Authorize.net's MD5 Hash End-of-Life affect CiviCRM?

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

Regarding: 
https://support.authorize.net/s/article/MD5-Hash-End-of-Life-Signature-Key-Replacement

> Authorize.Net is phasing out the MD5 based hash use for transaction response
>   verification in favor of the SHA-512 based hash utilizing a Signature
>   Key. The end of life for MD5 Hash will be done in two phases: Phase 1
>   - Starting later this month to early February 2019, we will remove ability to configure or update MD5 Hash setting in the Merchant
>   Interface. There are no changes to the existing API response.
>
> Phase 2 - Stop sending the MD5 Hash data element in the API response.
>   This change will require that applications support the SHA-512 hash
>   via signature key.  Dates for phase 2 will be announced later but is
>   expected in the next 2-3 months.
>
> When you receive a transaction response from Authorize.Net, it
>   includes the a SHA2 hash element the name and position depend on the
>   API integration method used. The SHA2 has field contains HMAC-SHA512
>   hash that Authorize.Net generated for the transaction.

Is CiviCRM's Authorize.net implementation affected?

Comment: Oops! I did search first, honest! :) Tried to close it as duplicate but apparently it needs more votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13474) from Monish to remove md5 hash support from Authorize.net payment processor in CiviCRM. Its now merged in master branch and should be part of 5.11 release.

Cheers

Pradeep